# Does time jump in android devices?

Tags: android, dalvik, ntp

**System.currentTimeMillis()** is giving wrong time.
It returns time values from 1980
Also time value taken through this function differs from actual time sometimes.
Some sample values returned by the function

```
315977198121
315965244789
316002166580
315982533137
```

Comment: If the device has a SIM card, it will (or should) automatically update the time from using the phone signal. In devices without a SIM card, such as a tablet, I've seen some incredible clock drift but nothing like this. What sort of device is this code running on? or is it an emulator?

Comment: @CurlyPaul  This code runs on android devices,especially Huawei Devices,not sure whats going wrong here

Comment: Also i am noticing values of 06 Jan 1980 a lot

Comment: `System.currentTimeMillis()` is just grabbing the time from the system clock.  If you're seeing weird values here you should also be seeing that date/time reflected in any clock in the user interface.  Are you?  This is a Java-language call, but you have android-ndk in your tags, which makes me wonder if you're calling the function from native code and are losing something at the language boundary.

Comment: @fadden I just added android-ndk, in hope of getting a larger audience for my issue. I am not sure but i have seen sometimes that the clock in user interface also drifts to the same time (06 Jan 1980), at least for the few cases i noticed.

Comment: "i have seen sometimes that the clock in user interface also drifts to the same time" -- then your device is seriously messed up.

Comment: Or the network you're connected to is seriously messed up.  Set airplane mode, make sure WiFi is disabled, and see if the time settles down.

Comment: While far from guaranteed, network driven system clock corrections might show up in logcat - at least they did on an Android 2.1 device that had a nasty habit of applying backwards corrections to CLOCK_MONOTONIC (!)

Comment: @CommonsWare have you heard this kind of issue before ?  [stackoverflow question link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11647047/android-device-time-set-to-6th-january-1980)

Comment: This is for an enterprise app running on devices which are connected to internet via 3G/2G, so WIFI is out of the question

Comment: hey @Commonsware the clock in Android UI freezing is a well-known bug from past versions, looks like they've solved it from 4.1, though

Comment: @rupps The issue is not with the display as such but with the above mentioned api System.currentTimeMillis()

Comment: yeah, sorry, it was a comment to another comment. Regarding your issue, I am following it with interest, I write software that relies heavily on that function and I haven't noticed it!

Comment: @DroidBoy, do these devices have an UI where a user can change the date/time manually? If they do, it's probably another reason why the time is jumping on them.

Comment: @DroidBoy I think you didn't understand fadden... Turn you device into flight mode, to disable all Network-Connections, Phone,Wifi,BT,... because Some 2G/3G Networks like to mess up your clock - like on my phone, everytime I visit france, my clock is reset to stupid values from the phone network, so I have to tur off automatic clock-adjustment und adjust it manually...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, time returned by System.currentTimeMillis() can jump around, for example because the device clock may have drifted, and is being reset due to fetching an accurate time from the network

Time as observed through other APIs may also jump around even more, for example due to changing time zones, or due to daylight saving.

(However that doesn't explain why you are seeing times suddenly in the 1980. That frankly sounds like a device error.)

You state that you are using the value to get a duration.  That's an error - you should be using SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() for duration calculations.

See the docs at [SystemClock](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/SystemClock.html), which specifically note:

```
Three different clocks are available, and they should not be confused:
```

- System.currentTimeMillis() is the standard "wall" clock (time and date) expressing milliseconds since the epoch. The wall clock can be set by the user or the phone network (see setCurrentTimeMillis(long)), so the time may jump backwards or forwards unpredictably. This clock should only be used when correspondence with real-world dates and times is important, such as in a calendar or alarm clock application. Interval or elapsed time measurements should use a different clock. If you are using System.currentTimeMillis(), consider listening to the ACTION_TIME_TICK, ACTION_TIME_CHANGED and ACTION_TIMEZONE_CHANGED Intent broadcasts to find out when the time changes.
- uptimeMillis() is counted in milliseconds since the system was booted. This clock stops when the system enters deep sleep (CPU off, display dark, device waiting for external input), but is not affected by clock scaling, idle, or other power saving mechanisms. This is the basis for most interval timing such as Thread.sleep(millls), Object.wait(millis), and System.nanoTime(). This clock is guaranteed to be monotonic, and is suitable for interval timing when the interval does not span device sleep. Most methods that accept a timestamp value currently expect the uptimeMillis() clock.
- elapsedRealtime() and elapsedRealtimeNanos() return the time since the system was booted, and include deep sleep. This clock is guaranteed to be monotonic, and continues to tick even when the CPU is in power saving modes, so is the recommend basis for general purpose interval timing.

Comment: DST will *not* affect `currentTimeMillis`. The time zone does not affect it at all - it's just a number of milliseconds since the Unix epoch.

Comment: Thanks Jon - edited answer to make it clear that time jumps due to daylight saving are observed via other APIs, not `currentTimeMillis`

Comment: Right. You might want to change the structure of the first paragraph now, given that your "variety of reasons" is now 1 :)

Comment: Buuuuut - currentTimeMillis my jump due to LeapSeconds ;-) (and of course due to 100 other reasons, user interaction, other software, whatever...) Using the right method for the right job - this is the best answer so far!

Answer (score 0):

Try using `System.nanoTime()` instead of `System.currentTimeMillis()`.

The documentation of `System.currentTimeMillis()` seems to indicate that it shouldn't be used for calculating time elapsed!

Answer (score 0):

you can create broadcastreceiver on action 'android.intent.action.TIME_SET'. You can know when time on your device change (by another applications).