# Objects not moving at the same speed, when Thread sleeps for a millisec

Tags: android

I am currently trying to move some rectangle objects (displayed as bitmaps on my surfaceview).
They should all move with the same speed, therefor my code looks like this:

```
new Thread (new Runnable() 
        {
            @Override
            public void run() 
            {

                while(true)
                {   
                        newTime =  System.currentTimeMillis();
                        frameTime = newTime - currentTime;
                        currentTime = newTime;

                        physics(frameTime);

                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(1);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                }
            }
        }).start();
```

i move my rectangle objects in the physics method based on the frametime parameter.

So my problem is the following: with the code i just posted all my rectangles move at the same speed, but the graphics are lagging. The lag disappears as soon as i remove the Thread.sleep(1), but then my rectangle objects wont move with the same speed anymore (some rectangles move faster than others).

any ideas?

Edit:

the physics and movedown methods are just normal methods in my classes, both are not in any threads or something. they are only getting called from my Thread i posted above

```
public void physics(double delta)
{
        for(int i=0; i<=5; i++)
        {
                rectangles[i].moveDown(delta);
        }
}

public void moveDown(double delta)
{
        setY((double) (getY() + ((sH)*(delta/1000)))); 
                //sH is the screen height
}
```

Edit2:

Graphics code

```
while(true)
        {

            if(!ourHolder.getSurface().isValid())
            {
                continue;
            }
            Canvas canvas = ourHolder.lockCanvas();
            synchronized(ourHolder) {
                graphics(canvas);   
                // in this method all the drawings happen
                // e.g. canvas.drawBitmap
            }
            ourHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to analyse given the code you posted, since it's unclear what `physics(frameTime);` is actually doing. It seems like each moving rectangle is updated in its own Thread. Then the result you get has to be expected because one thread or the other will be called more often than the others depending on thread scheduling. Instead, use one single thread to control your simulation (e.g. update your `frameTime` and provide it to the other threads). However, IMHO you have to rethink your architecture.

Comment: I understand your point, but i cant see any problem with my architecture. I have added some code, maybe you can have a look again? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell from your posted code what the problem could be, but one thing I notice is that you could experience some clock drift. See: [Does time jump in android devices?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22377219/does-time-jump-in-android-devices).

Although, it looks like you are moving the rectangles using a fixed offset, so even if there were clock drift, I would expect them to jump around but by the same amount. So I agree with Axel that there appears to be some thread interaction going on.

How are you drawing to the screen? If you have another thread processing the graphics, the two threads could get out of sync and you'll need to ensure you are locking things properly. If you are using the deltas to update the location on the screen in your paint method, maybe instead use an absolute position that you update in your physics() method and draw based on that. It seems you probably need to rethink some of the architecture.

Comment: Indeed I am drawing in another Thread. I have added the code to my original post. In the graphics(canvas) method the Bitmaps are drawn with their object coordinates (rectangle.getX() and Y). Any ideas?